# Grails, GORM, update method persists object before calling save()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain Class `DailyBooking` and a generated Controller. In the update function I'm calling `userService.computeFlexTime(dailyBookingInstance)`. There I want to get the current persisted entry from DailyBooking (from the database):

```
DailyBooking currentEntry = DailyBooking.findByUserAndDate(dailyBookingInstance.user, dailyBookingInstance.date)
```

From my understanding I should get the current persisted entry from the database because I'm calling the service before the save statement in the update function. But when I actually debug, currentEntry has values from the updated object. Additionally the new values are already written in the database without calling save.

update method:

```
if(dailyBookingInstance.end != null){
        userService.computeFlexTime(dailyBookingInstance)
    }

    dailyBookingInstance.save flush:true
```

Another question is why does this method has an effect on the dailyBookingInstance in my Controller since its not returned? I think in Java I would have to work with `ref` or smth. like that.

Comment: In transactionnal services, objects retrieved from the database (or newly created and saved) are automatically persisted after method execution.

Comment: Can I change that? I need in currentEntry an object with the values before the update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with the [getPersistentValue function](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/getPersistentValue.html)